# Python exits without finishing script

Tags: python

I keep getting The thread 'MainThread' (0x1) has exited with code 0 (0x0). before the script has even fully reached the end. I have some extra parts to my script after a while num < maxthreads loop but it seems like the interpretor is exiting right after this condition is met. I want it to continue after this, what am I doing wrong?

```
def creator():
    s = requests.session()
    email = randomName()
    password = randomPassword()
    name = names.get_full_name()

    data={
    "displayname":name,
    "creation_point":"https://login.app.igloo.com?utm_source",
    "birth_month":monthnumber,
    "email":email + "@gmail.com",
    "password":password,
    }

try:

    r = s.post("https://spclient.wg.igloo.com/signup/public/v1/account/",data=data,proxies=proxy1.FormatProxy())
    if '{"status":1,"' in r.text:
        open("creatediglooaccountsgen.txt", "a+").write(email + "@gmail.com:" + password + ":" + PROXY + "\n")
        created += 1
    else:
        errors += 1
except:
    pass
    print("DONE")
maxi = 4
maxthreads = 4
num = 0

while num < maxthreads:
    num += 1
    threading.Thread(target=creator).start()  # Start Checking Thread
chrome = webdriver.chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://igloo.com/en/login")
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



#from selenium findElement
with open('creatediglooaccountsgen.txt') as f:
    credentials = [x.strip().split(':', 1) for x in f]
for username, password in credentials:
@type='text']")
@type='text'").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id("login-username").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id("login-password").send_keys(password)
try:
    time.sleep(10)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Log In']"))).click()
except:
    print('exception occured')
time.sleep(3)

driver.close()
```

I've tried to cut out as much as I can to condense it but essentially the script stops after the `while num < maxthreads` line (after the specified 4 loops since maxi is set to 4) but I want it to continue after that.

Any ideas,
thanks

Comment: The first thing you need to do to find out what's actually going wrong is delete your blanket `try/except` statements. That may give you a meaningful stack trace.

Comment: is this for the first or second try/except?

Comment: Both. You should almost never swallow exceptions like that.

Comment: Use debugger https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb, it will allow you to run your code line by line and find exact place and error.

Comment: There are no errors, it just completes the program without finishing the lines after the ```while num < maxthreads``` loop.